# Remove UILocalNotifications from Notification center

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to remove notifications from the notification center.
I found out the following code which has been supplied by another stackoverflow user:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
```

I tried adding that code to the AppDelegate.m below

applicationWillEnterForeground

But whenever I tap a notification from the notification center it doesn't go away in the notification center itself.

What am I doing wrong?
I can't use "CancelAllNotifications" because I have pre-scheduled notifications in the future to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my tests, it looks like we need to cancel the existing local notifications in addition to calling `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:`

Since you want to keep any upcoming notifications in the system, just doing a simple cancel obviously won't work.  Therefore the strategy I'd go with is to add those remaining notifications to a new array, and then re-set that array as the collection of `scheduledLocalNotifications.`  It may seem a bit odd to read the collection and then re-set it, however according to the documentation, setting the `scheduledLocalNotifications` property invokes `cancelLocalNotification:` first... which is exactly what we want to do.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
NSArray *notifications = [UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications = notifications;
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it cancels all the other notifications to that I pre-scheduled if I'm not mistaking?

Comment: Okay, I'll wait to find out if somebody else knows.

Comment: Thanks for the work around, only it doesn't work as it should be I guess. It removes the notification from the notification center but future alarms don't pop-up anymore.

Comment: Hmm... mine still pop-up. I'm not sure what's different between our two tests.

Comment: I think I might know why, I included this in the AppDelegate and all my notifications are set-up in a viewcontroller IBAction so I guess that the reason why they just cancel. Also, did you test this in the simulator or on a real device?

Comment: @user1839995 Real device... iPhone 4s w/ iOS 6.  I did just the opposite: notifications created in AppDelegate and IBAction runs the above code. After pushing the button, I verified that the notification was removed from the Notification Center and that future notifications still alerted.

Comment: Tested on a real device now to (iPhone 5 iOS 6.1) and it didn't work. I do have an idea in my head and I'll try if it works when I have time again. Thanks for the solution. I will accept it because it helped!

Comment: I was able to simplify the code even more... it occurred to me that comparing dates was redundant, since the old notifications would have already been removed from the collection.

Comment: The simplified code works even better, thanks my goal has been achieved now :)